# align-content doesn't work with chrome grid

Tags: html, css

When i used these codes they dont work especially align-content doesnt work for chrome .

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,100px);
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(87, 217, 93);">1</div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">2</div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(230, 73, 115);">3</div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);">4</div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(221, 245, 7);">5</div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `align-content`? Please be as thorough as possible so we can help you.

Comment: Hi can you explain your problem more?  This code seems to be working fine.

Comment: align-content:center ,space-between or end dont work. i don't know why. i am writing exactly the same however nothing changes.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? And you are wanting the `div`'s centered inside of `.container`?

Comment: maybe you mean to use `justify-content:center;` instead of `align-content:center;`

Comment: no i am not using bootstrap, this div.container  has got 6 divs with different colors. i just want to this div  to change its position vertically by using align-content. but it doesnt work so strange. i am watching in this video  41:25 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6CBKf8K_Ac ...  but i couldnt..

Comment: what if i want to change the div position vertically dont i have to use align-content property ?

Comment: @halilibrahimtosun I updated my answer I posted. Please look.  I solved your issue.

Comment: @John i want to change the divs vertically. just above the youtube videos. but i cant do it with padding. i think the wrong is giving any padding size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `justify-content` instead of `align-content`  Here's an example with `justify-content:space-between;`

EDIT: I figured out what you wanted, its bacuse you were giving your border space with padding only at the bottom and it wasn't adjusting to it. Change `padding-bottom` to just `padding` You're align-content: center is indeed working. Here look what I did.

```css
.container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 100%;
  padding: 25%;
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 100px);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(2,100px);
 /*justify-content: center;*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div style="background-color: rgb(87, 217, 93);">1</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">2</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(230, 73, 115);">3</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);">4</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(221, 245, 7);">5</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">6</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use fractions like this

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
    /* justify-content: center; */
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.container div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And the result will be like in the picture.

[image]

If you want a more grouped solution, you have to district container to fixe width and Positionate the container to center, or use flex.

OR formate DIV

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(87, 217, 93);">1</div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">2</div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(230, 73, 115);">3</div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);">4</div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(221, 245, 7);">5</div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here:

```
div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    width: fit-content;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
    /* justify-content: center; */
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now i solved them. Giving padding size isnot working with align-content.
i deleted  padding size and gave the div heigh and width.

```css
.container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 100%;
   /*padding-bottom: 25%;*/
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 100px);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(2,100px);
 /*justify-content: center;*/
   align-content: end;
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div style="background-color: rgb(87, 217, 93);">1</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">2</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(230, 73, 115);">3</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);">4</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(221, 245, 7);">5</div>
 <div style="background-color: rgb(227, 84, 18);">6</div>
  
 </div>
```